# How to add a loading event listener to an object javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, sprite

I am currently working on a game with sprites in javascript, and I wanted to add an event listener that checks whether the sprite images are loaded or not before it starts the game. I am using object-oriented programing, and I have ran into some issues with this... I will show an example of what i have in mind:

```
function Sprite() {
    this.img = new Image();
    // either this:
    this.img.onload = function() {
    }
    // or this:
    this.img.addEventListener("load", function() {
        // Either way, when it loads, then it could proceed with the move or draw methods.
        // I don't even know how to do this yet...
    });

    this.img.src = "res/image.png";

    this.draw = function() {
        context.drawImage(//with all the parameters);
    }

    this.move = function() {
        // code that makes the sprites move
    }
}
```

Either way, and any way that I have tried it, it doesn't work without showing any errors. It just doesn't display the sprites. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: well is the error event being triggered if the load is not firing?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `this.img.onerror = function(){}`

Comment: that doesnt really do anything. or at least i am not aware of what it should be doing... sorry

Comment: Did you add logging inside on the onerror to see if it is triggered.... that was just the basic idea.... Learn to use your console and network panel to see if the request went out to get the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make capture semantics explicit with `var self = this;`. By referencing `this` in a variable called `self`, you will be able to call `self.draw` inside the Sprite's image load function.

The problem might be that you were trying `this.draw` inside the onload, but `this` in that case refers to the anonymous function and not the Sprite. See example below.

Aside, I think what the commenters are suggesting is you have an error in the loading of your image. Here's an example that works using an image from one of the cdn that stack overflow uses:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Sprite() {

    var self = this;
    self.img = new Image();

    self.draw = function() {
        context.drawImage(self.img, 0, 0);
    }

    self.move = function() {
        // code that makes the sprites move
    }

    // or this:
    self.img.addEventListener("load", function() {
        self.draw();
    });

    self.img.src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=78be252218f3g";
}

var s = new Sprite();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: okay, that at least draws the sprite the way I want, but the problem is that I want to call the draw and move methods outside the object, inside an interval in a separate function... But thanks anyways

Comment: See how I stored the sprite in a variable called `s` ? Now, you can do `s.move()` and `s.draw()` anywhere you want in a program.... `setTimeout(function() { s.draw(); s.move(); }, 15);` would call draw and move on your sprite every 15 milliseconds for example.

Comment: I know. That's how I was originally planning to do it. The thing is that it doesnt work. It works if i draw it with `self.draw()` from within the event listener but it doesnt work when i call it with s.draw() from another function

Comment: It works from my end - what I've done in my last edit is comment out the self.draw in the load function and simply use it on the Sprite instance I've instantiated. Calling self.draw elsewhere in code should work as in the example I've provided.

Comment: Link your fiddle. I run into nuances working with Fiddles that aren't what I expect in JavaScript elsewhere.

Comment: Oh wait... that really is weird as it suddenly works

Comment: yeah but that must be beacause the event listener is not doing anything now, so it's just as if it wasn't there. And i meant code snippet, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165598/discussion-between-jakub-chaloupka-and-thisclark).